# Can't pass a list of objects to the view using JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The data is passed from the controller to the view using AJAX call
but for some reason I am not able to retrieve it using JavaScript
the data shows an list on empty object!

[image: Image : what i see in my browser]

```
public class Ville {
    string wilPop { get; set; }// = null;
    int identifiant { get; set; }// = -1;
    bool affectedD { get; set; } //= false;

    public Ville(string ewilPop, int eidentifiant, bool eaffectedD)
    {
        this.wilPop = ewilPop;
        this.identifiant = eidentifiant;
        this.affectedD = eaffectedD;
    }

}
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetWilByRegion(int? Wil)
{
    if (Wil != null)
    {
        string wilPop = null;
        int identifiant = -1;
        bool affectedD = false;

        //Get info from DB
        List<city> ListWil = new List<city>();
        ListWil = db.city.Where(m => m.idReg == Wil).OrderByDescending(m => m.population).ToList();
        List<Ville> mylist = new List<Ville>();

        foreach (city item in ListWil)
        {
            // Description in the DB
            wilPop = item.city + " (" + item.population + ")"; 
            // id value in the DB
            identifiant = item.city_id; 
            // if checked or not
            affectedD = CheckifWilAffected(item.city_id); 
            mylist.Add(new Ville(wilPop, identifiant, affectedD)); 
        }
        return Json(mylist, "Ville");

    }
    else return Json("Error");
}
```

`mylist` is not empty, it contains all the data (after debugging the controller)

This is my AJAX call :

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { Wil: _idr },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
      var markup = "";

      for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
          markup += '<input type=' + '"checkbox"' + ' name=' + data[x].wilPop + ' value=' + data[x].identifiant + '>' + data[x].wilPop + '</input>' + '<br/>';
      }            
      $("#chWil").html(markup).show();
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error - can't do the ajax call - please check your code..." );
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the `Ville` class

Comment: Attach debugger to the controller. Is it returning data? Watch Ajax call in Fiddler. Does the response have an expected format and content? Attach debugger to javascript (Chrome tools). Does `data` have anything in it?

Comment: mylist contain all the info, but when i attach the debugger to java script data is empty (list of {},{},{},{},{},{},{})

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an array of empty objects(*without any properties*) because your `Ville` class does not have any **public** properties.

You need to make your properties `public`

```
public class Ville
{
    public string wilPop { get; set; }
    public int identifiant { get; set; }
    public bool affectedD { get; set; }

    public Ville(string ewilPop, int eidentifiant, bool eaffectedD)
    {
        this.wilPop = ewilPop;
        this.identifiant = eidentifiant;
        this.affectedD = eaffectedD;
    }
}
```

Now the JavaScript serializer will be able to use the values of those properties when creating a JSON string representation of your list.

I personally like to use **P**ascal**C**asing for class property names.( `WilPop` instead of `wilPop`)